# RPC call using the solana python library throws error on AsyncClient

Tags: python, blockchain, smartcontracts, rpc, solana

I have the following code:

```
from solana.rpc.async_api import AsyncClient
async_client = AsyncClient(endpoint="https://go.getblock.io/77fe047d82cc43eda038133a17c60b18")
```

It throws the following error:

```
TypeError: AsyncConnectionPool.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'socket_options'
```

I'm not able to get it working

Comment: You may be conflating two different examples -- your two lines of code work great!